# How to send commands to telnet and leave session open

Tags: unix, pipe, telnet

I have to connect to a remote server via telnet and want to send file input there.

This is a processor emulator (MCF68k), so I can't just scp the file to the server and run from there.

I can send input like this:

`telnet host.name < input.file`

Which will successfully transmit the data to the server and run the commands stored that I want.
However, I need the telnet session to stay interactive (not terminate).

How do I pipe a file to a command, then return control of stdin to the terminal and keep the interactive session open?

**Very Late Edit**:

I think this can be done using `expect`:

man expect: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/

python wrapper: http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: The screen utility might do what you need.  http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Comment: No way is this offtopic. It would be superuser except that the pre-interactive input could be considered programming.

Comment: @Will, did you actually read the FAQ? "the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers ... software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: @Jack Yeah, I read it.  By my best judgement it's off topic.  I know programmers use telnet, however that doesn't mean its on topic.  How, exactly, is it programming related?  If you make a good argument I can always reopen.  Or you can flag for mod attention and make your case there.

Comment: @Will: Well, for starters, this would've been really handy to know for the MUD server I'm building: to be able to keep a prelude handy for login, &c. and then pass control to telnet for interactive testing. Telnet's also a great toolbox program for poking at servers for testing and given its insecurity, I can't see it being a user tool at all.

Comment: @Jack I can totally see how a question like "how can I use telnet to see if a sql server is up and ready" would be programming related, but that doesn't mean every and all telnet questions are programming related.  Look, if I felt this question was actually related to application development in any way whatsoever I'd reopen it in a heartbeat.  But it is not about programming, it is about keeping a telnet session interactive.  That's a question about how the telnet application works, and would be best answered on unix.stackexchange.com or SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: @Will: Then why did you close the question as opposed to migrating it?

Comment: @Jack SuperUser site users are... not exactly happy with being a dumping ground for offtopic questions from StackOverflow.  Same goes for ServerFault.  Frankly, I'm not sure where it should go.  It might go to three different sites (the ones I listed).  You know how you're chewing on my butt about closing this as off topic?  Had my butt chewed for migrating questions that were eventually closed as off topic on the destination site.  If Jamie (who is probably sitting back laughing at me over this) would like, I can migrate it for him.

Comment: @Will: Fair enough. Sounds like the better option would then be to just let the questions migrate based on user votes. The question really does sound on-topic for both superuser and unix stackexchange, from looking at each FAQ page.

Comment: @Jack what you don't see are the people flagging the question for mod attention.  Lots of active users who either don't have enough rep to vote to close, or just dont for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Does `cat input.file - | telnet host.name` work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Although that does seem to work for other commands, such as `cat input.file - | xxd`. It seems that the telnet connection is using `getch` or some equivalent - don't know if that's messing with it or what.

Comment: Irritating. I can't think of anything else off-hand, sorry.

Comment: This may not work due to flushing of `stdin`, and maybe the fact that input will not be from a tty? What a pain.